#  How to launch GNOME Shell Extension Preferences from the Main Menu?

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

Is it only possible to adjust extensions from Browser or CLI? (The command for it is `gnome-shell-extension-prefs`) Can I add a Main Menu entry for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [alacarte](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/alacarte) [image: Install alacarte] to create a Main menu entry.

[image]

Just add `gnome-shell-extension-prefs` in the relevant command field and you should have it in the Main Menu.

[image]